# SSIS job packages backup and restore

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

this should be a simple task. But I couldn't find straightforward answer in Google. How to take backup of SSIS packages from database instance just as like normal database backup is taken, and how to restore it in different database instance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the management of SQL Server Integration Services packages and not about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to the Integration Services instance, right-click the package you want to move to another server, and select "Export package...". Change the "Protection level" for the package to "Do not save sensitive data with user key".

Then on the destination Integration Services instance, right-click the MSDB folder and select "Import Package..." and change the Protection level, if necessary.

Differences between package-level protection can be researched here:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/eric_johnson/archive/2010/01/12/understanding-the-ssis-package-protection-level.aspx

If you want to backup and restore an entire SSIS Catalog, detailed steps can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213291(v=sql.110).aspx